# Free Report Designer(Generator) like Crystal Report , Fast Report and etc

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, report

I am looking for a free report designer, like Crystal Report ,Fast Report ,Stimul ,etc for my WinFom Application.My Applaction database is sql server 2005.thanks.

I have tried in google but I didn't find any useful one.Now I am using Microsoft Report in my application.

**Update** : I have found this one [OpenReport](http://www.xtuple.com/openrpt/),Has anyone exprienced this one?

Comment: Looking at the link in your Update, I see that OpenReport (haven't used it myself) would need some work to work with the SQL Server 2005 which you are using.

Comment: Thanks to OpenReport Group.I had a look at OpenReport and I guess it is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I have used the built in reports in Visual Studio, they were much easier to work with than Crystal Reports and had no problems in dealing with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple report containing not more than 5 pages, you can use the quick demo version of the report. I use it quite successfully.